# How can i store an array into localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

var listArray = [];
localStorage.setItem("cookie", listArray);
//listArray is a array here, I want the cookie to get stored like an array, is this even possible?

Comment: Serialise it with `JSON.stringify()` then deserialise it when reading back with `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Could you send it in code please. I tried that and I simply didn't get it right :(